# How to multiply instances of SVG?

Tags: javascript, svg

My goal is to create a very simple bar graph, and I am using SVG for it. Since a bar graph can contain multiple rectangles, can I multiply instances of a rectangle, for example?

I have this sample code:

```
<rect id="myRect" height="50" width="100" fill="blue" y="500" x="0"/>
```

It is an external SVG that is being called by this code:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","svg/rect.svg",false);
xhr.send("");
document.getElementById("svgContainer")
  .appendChild(xhr.responseXML.documentElement);
```

Is this possible? Or is even my approach correct?

Answer (score 2):

Appending *n* copies of the SVG is not a particularly efficient approach to doing this.  It would work, but it is not what I would recommend.

A much better approach would be to build the graph yourself by creating `rect` elements in JS and appending them to an `<svg>` element.

Or alternatively, there are are number of SVG graphing libraries (such as d3js) which are designed to make this sort of thing easy.